# Sort entity list in the MDS(2016) explorer

Tags: mds

How can I sort the entity list in MDS explorer - version 2016. When I was browsing the explorer, I thought the list of entities are alphabetically sorted. But, to my surprise, they are not. Please help me fix this issue.
Eg. I currently have entities shown as xyz, abc, lmn, iop. I want them to be listed as abc, iop, lmn, xyz. Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't seen this before nor could see some settings to change it. So, couldn't try anything. Anything in particular I should be trying?

Comment: Hi guys, I am still waiting for some help. Alternatively, have you got any suggestions? Thanks